# Adding rewriterule to htaccess ignores JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, apache, .htaccess

I have added `htaccess` rewrite rule to make the link easier to remember or just to look better, for example, everything works on http://localhost/moviescat.php?id=Action but nothing works on http://localhost/movies/genre/Action

Here is my code for it:

```
Options -Multiviews
 
# Mod Rewrite
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d


RewriteRule ^([a-z_]+)\/?$ $1.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /profile/?user_username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /profile/?user_username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)$ /post.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/$ /post.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/false$ /post.php?id=$1&false [L]
RewriteRule ^post/([^/]*)/false/$ /post.php?id=$1&false [L]

RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)$ /movie.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/$ /movie.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/false$ /movie.php?id=$1&false [L]
RewriteRule ^movie/([^/]*)/false/$ /movie.php?id=$1&false [L]

RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([^/]*)$ /moviescat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([^/]*)/$ /moviescat.php?id=$1 [L]



RewriteRule ^edit/([^/]*)$ /edit.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^edit/([^/]*)/$ /edit.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/([^/]*)$ /delete.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^delete/([^/]*)/$ /delete.php?id=$1 [L]

RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/likes/$ /profile/likes.php/?user_username=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/likes$ /profile/likes.php/?user_username=$1 [L]


RewriteRule ^post/add/$ /post/add.php [L]
RewriteRule ^post/add$ /post/add.php [L]
```

and here is JavaScript for this:

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function(){
         $('#loader').on('inview', function(event, isInView) {
             if (isInView) {
                 var nextPage = parseInt($('#pageno').val())+1;
                 $.ajax({
                     type: 'POST',
                     url: '../../paginationmovies.php',
                     data: { pageno: nextPage },
                     success: function(data){
                         if(data != ''){                             
                             $('#response').append(data);
                             $('#pageno').val(nextPage);
                         } else {                                
                             $("#loader").hide();
                         }
                     }
                 });
             }
         });
     });
 </script>
```

Interesting is that everything works on http://localhost/movies/

It's like `htaccess` is ignoring this part of the JavaScript:

```
url: '../../paginationmovies.php',
```

Comment: What doesn't work as expected? Does that file exist? Use your browser's DevTools/Network tab to see if the request is made. Where/in which folder is that javascript file located?

Comment: I want it to work like this - http://localhost/movies/genre/Action or any other genre /Adventure etc. But the javascript file only works on http://localhost/moviescat.php?id=Action . Javascript is located - in - localhost/template/pages/infinitescrollmovies.php and I'm inlucing it below in the code in http://localhost/moviescat.php . And yes, file exists, the same file works on http://localhost/movies/index.php OR http://localhost/movies , javascript loads and works just fine, but it just seems to be ignored in this link /movies/genre/Action , but it works in this /moviescat.php?id=Action

Comment: You changed the URL of your main document, so of course this affects how any relative URLs get resolved. Most commonly used and easy solution: Use paths that start with a `/` to address all resources from the domain root, so that the path level depth of the main document URL does not influence this any more.

Comment: No, the URL is correct. I'm sure of it. I tried to change it anyways but it just doesn't work either way. Here's the screenshots - https://imgur.com/a/gCgMxlE
In the first screenshot you can see that loader disappears, everything works as it should, In the second screenshot nothing works, because I changed the URL with .htaccess, and in the last, 3rd screenshot, I've entered the URL of php script, which is not changed in .htaccess and everything works and loads as it should....

Comment: I tried it even like this `var temp_url = "/paginationmovies.php";` and then `url: temp_url,` **AND** even like this  `var temp_url = "http://mysiteurl.com/paginationmovies.php";` and it still works only on **/movies/**, **/moviescat.php?id=Action**, and it doesnt work on **/movies/genre/Action**, please, help me someone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem, was in `htaccess`.

Changed lines from this:

```
RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([^/]*)$ /moviescat.php?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([^/]*)/$ /moviescat.php?id=$1 [L]
```

to this:

```
RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ /movies/genre/?id=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^movies/genre/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ /movies/genre/?id=$1 [L]
```